# Passing Label1.Text to ascx File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tags, inline, ascx

How do I reference my Label1 control on my aspx page in my inline Control line?

I am bringing in an ascx file and cant do this simple thing:

```
<uc1:ContactsListforCompanies ID="ContactsListforCompanies1" runat="server" CompanyID=<%= Label1.text %> />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom control you have to use biding <%#Label1.Text%> and call databind() method on the control

Comment: This doesnt work for some reason, if I replace <%= or <%# with a numerical value to test, the control works and yes I have databinding in place.

Comment: How about using quotes? `CompanyID="<%# Label1.text %>"`.

Comment: Nope, nothing!! Dont get an error or anything. Just no gridview to my control within the file

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your custom control is part of datacontrol

```
CompanyID=<%# BindLabel() %>
```

In codeBehind

```
string BindLabel()
{
  return Label1.Text;
}
```

OR

Add in Page_Load

```
ContactsListforCompanies1.CompanyID = Label1.Text;
```

Comment: I think I may have discovered the issue! I am using a DNN Environment and there is some protection level error happening without creating an on page issue. I have built a work-round!! Not completely happy but I am using a Session Variable alongside my label control. Thanks all